# Spark AR Native UI Picker disable options

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I am developing a filter in Spark and i have one question. I am doing a game, and I have 4 diferent options, the player can choose 1 2 3 or 4. When the user clicks, for example, in option 1, the option 2, 3 and 4 become invisible and option 1 visible. But i need to disable the option 2, 3 and 4 because they are invisible, but running, so i lose the game because i hit in a invisible enemy. How can i do that? I really need when the user choose one option to disable the other and not just put them invisible/visible (I am using P[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/174V0.png)icker UI)

Answer (score 0):

did you tried a Pulse option after the Equals exactlys, when you selected for example oprtion 1 all the other 3 oprions will turn off. Let me know if it worked for you, or if you figured it out how to do it.